# How to raise an exception if use input is not in a list,i get stuck in a loop

Tags: python

```
def main():
    i = input("Enter a File Extension You Wish To seek!")
    while i not in document_extensions:
        print(input("Enter a Valid Extension:"))

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input("Enter a Directory:"), topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=True):
            for name in files:
                if name.endswith(i):
                    print(os.path.join(root, name))
            for name in dirs:
                if name.endswith(i):
                    print(os.path.join(root, name))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

while True:
    try:
        x = open(input("Enter Path To File You Wish To View!"), "r", encoding="utf-8")
        y = x.read()
        print(y)
        x.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Enter a Valid Path!")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Do a bit of research on the `raise` statement, and the applicable exception classes.

Comment: thank you for you quick , im very new to this the program seems to be running the way i intend now <3

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do - and where you want to raise error. Maybe better describe problem in question's body (not in title, not in comments)